# Bring information of two layer deep child objects into a table with minimum usage of heap

Tags: apex, soql

We have a scenario to bring information into a visualforce table (which will be displayed in the form of a excel sheet). The base object is Order, which is parent object of hearing(lookup). And hearing is the parent object of invoice(master-detail). We need to have information from all three object's fields. We need the information of only one field from invoice which is a text field.

If there are multiple hearings attached to one order, we will display all of them. If there are multiple invoice attached to one hearing, we will only display the first one.

Originally, we had only order and hearing objects and we had a SOQL query like this:

```
Select Id, CaseNumber, ... (Select Id, Name, ... From Hearings__r) From Order__c
```

And we examined that we need to limit this query to 5000 records if we want to play it safe due to limit size.

Since SOQL won't allow me use two layer-deep query in parent-child relationship, I guess the best thing I can do here is to use a map and capture the related invoice information if I stick with implementing just inside the controller class. Since, however, will significantly increase the heap size usage and will bring down the current number of records we can handle, which we don't want to see.

Another solution we came across is the pre-populate the related information into hearing. As the field in invoice is a text field, I don't think roll-up summary will apply here. So I am assuming the only thing we could do is via trigger. However, that means we need to handle the millions of existing data as well which can be a pain.

Any suggestions for this?

Comment: how many records you want to display on VFP? are you thinking of pagination?

Comment: @SantanuBoral It is actually rendered as a excel sheet to be downloaded. So should display as many as possible

Comment: Why not just pull all the information from the lowest level object? You can easily go up two levels.

Comment: @AdrianLarson The current reason is there are two child objects of order which I need to retrieve information from. I didn't mention that in order to make it simple.